# Does CREATE TABLE ... SELECT respect ORDER BY for AUTO_INCREMENT column?

Tags: mysql

Will `counter` be ordered exactly the same way as `SELECT` outputs according to `ORDER BY` instruction so that `counter` will have strictly sequential values within `userid`?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Tmp(
  counter BIGINT not null auto_increment,
  primary key (counter)
) SELECT userid, itemid
FROM Items WHERE typeid=5 ORDER BY userid;
```

As far as I tested it works but is it really guaranteed in all cases? It would be nice to have some reference to mysql docs (docs on `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` doesn't cover that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most relevant doc I've found is [17.4.1.1 Replication and AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-auto-increment.html) which seems to guarantee the ordering at least when using `INSERT INTO`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Tmp(
  counter BIGINT not null auto_increment,
  userid BIGINT not null,
  itemid INT not null,
  primary key (counter)
);
INSERT INTO Tmp SELECT userid, itemid
FROM Items WHERE typeid=5 ORDER BY userid;
```

Will use that syntax if no one answer something better.